Groupby and Transform and Regression
I am trying to get the residuals from a simple regression. This regressions is run by each Year and Group. This is what I have done. Howevevr, is there a way to get that residuals as a new columns along with original dataframe?
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['a','b','c','d','e','a','b','c','d','e','a','b','c','d','e'],
                 'Year':[2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022],
                'Group':['H','L','N','N','N','H','L','N','N','N','H','L','N','N','N'],
                'Value':[0.3,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1],
                'Mom':[5,1,3,5,2,1,1,3,6,4,4,7,8,3,2]})

def a(row):
    X = row['Value']  # independent variable
    y = row['Mom']   # dependent variable
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    reg = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
    
    return reg.resid

df.groupby(['Year','Group']).apply(a)


I can certainly append the above output to original dataframe but I am trying to achieve this by transform. I have tried this but it didn't work out. Also, becuase my dataset is very larget ~8GB, so if anyone could provide a numpy version soluition to speed things up?
df.groupby(['Year','Group']).transform(a)



I'm not sure you can do this with transform.
You can, on the other hand, modify the function you're applying to each group to achieve the behaviour you're looking for:
def a(group):
    X = group["Value"]  # independent variable
    y = group["Mom"]  # dependent variable
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    group["Residual"] = sm.OLS(y, X).fit().resid
    return group

df.groupby(["Year", "Group"], group_keys=False).apply(a)

   Name  Year Group  Value  Mom Residual
0     a  2020     H    0.3    5      0.0
1     b  2020     L    0.2    1      0.0
2     c  2020     N    0.3    3      0.0
3     d  2020     N    0.1    5      1.5
4     e  2020     N    0.1    2     -1.5
5     a  2021     H    0.2    1      0.0
6     b  2021     L    0.3    1      0.0
7     c  2021     N    0.2    3     -1.5
8     d  2021     N    0.2    6      1.5
9     e  2021     N    0.1    4      0.0
10    a  2022     H    0.4    4      0.0
11    b  2022     L    0.1    7      0.0
12    c  2022     N    0.1    8      3.0
13    d  2022     N    0.3    3     -0.0
14    e  2022     N    0.1    2     -3.0

